# How to start building the racing levels in unity?

Tags: unity, game-design, level-design

I had an idea of making more fun less redundantly designed level for a racing game, i have core mechanics and ui of the game sorted out but i m confused where to begin with the levels and how do i structure them. link of any sites that focusses on this would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try building some roads with some tools like:

https://github.com/MicroGSD/RoadArchitect
or
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/easyroads3d-free-v3-987

Then you can use some more assets and props like:

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/props/exterior/road-props-low-poly-123340
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/environments/urban/city-voxel-pack-136141
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/props/exterior/traffic-and-vehicle-accessories-71194

All in all don't expect to think of a complete level/scene, go bit by bit and your imagination will follow :D

You can also find more tools for the terrain here: https://assetstore.unity.com/tools/terrain?category=tools%2Fterrain&orderBy=4

And ask for further help here:
https://forum.unity.com/forums/world-building.146/

Comment: As well as this you could look at real world racetracks or, have a look at the Scalextric racing system.  There are plenty of online tracks that could be converted to game form.

Comment: it was a great help thanks guys!!

Comment: Please note that questions asking "how to get started" or requesting lists of resources are not considered on-topic for this particular site. This is better suited to [chat], a discussion forum, or #gamedev social media channels. Here we focus on targeted problem-solving where we can identify a "correct" answer — something that doesn't really apply to lists or the unlimited valid ways to start a game project.